# SQL statement to list employees by salary with updated yearly bonus, CONCAT

Tags: sql

Problem:
The salary shown in the table is monthly.
Each employee receives a bonus once a year. The bonus for each employee is equal to their years of experience multiplied by 500.

Write a query to output the firstname and lastname columns into one column named fullname separated by space, and the total annual salary for each employee keeping in mind bonuses named 'total'. Sort by the 'total' column.

TIP: Use CONCAT function and AS keyword.

Heres what I have so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT (firstname, ' ', lastname, ',') AS fullname
SET salary = experience*500+salary
```

I tried placing the salary = in () in the first SELECT, as well as a 2nd SELECT statement but keep getting errors.

expected output:

```
fullname,total
Lisa Anderson,17100
John Smith,19000
David Gibson,22500
Nelson Gross,23300
Seth Gray,27000
```

Comment: `SET` does not belong in a `SELECT` statement. It is only used in an `UPDATE` when you're altering the content of one or more columns. Your assignment wants you to OUTPUT the salary with bonuses, not set the SALARY column to a new value. Try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set` isn't a command for SELECT queries. You are confusing that with an UPDATE.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_select.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

You also need to multiply the salary by 12, as it's stored monthly.

Get rid of the `Set` and use "total" as your alias and you should be good to go. Well, you still need the sorting/ORDER BY operation.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_order_by.asp

```
SELECT CONCAT (firstname, ' ', lastname, ',') AS fullname,
  (experience * 500) + (salary * 12) as total
  FROM table_name
  ORDER BY total
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "firstname" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT CONCAT (firstname, ' ', lastname, ',') AS fullname,
                       ^
The SELECT CONCAT was working before, I just couldn't figure out how to create/concat the column for updated salary. Now I'm getting this error for concat/fullname.

Comment: @Travis, you hadn't included the table name, so I forgot to add that to the query. I've updated my answer. You need to make sure the table and columns match in order to avoid those errors.

Comment: Thanks so much... Everything's perfect, but the output has " " around the names. The ' ' are not outputting as a space, either.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there are extra spaces in the names when they were input, so you need a `TRIM` function for each of the "firstname" and "lastname" columns https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_trim.asp

Comment: Got it, thank you. I'm trying to learn!

Comment: @Travis, yeah, there's a lot to learn, and most of it are "tricks of the trade" rather than just the pure language. There's plenty to learn with the language, but knowing to trim the names is something usually gained by experience rather than a book, as you are experiencing. Good luck and try to have fun!